# Exporting the SVM Results from R

Tags: r, user-interface, svm

I have build a classification model using `SVM` in `R`. I want to export the results such that it can be used to create a GUI in R. The model must be implemented for prediction of class outcome from unknown data. I am not able to find the method to export the model.

Kindly help me with the steps to follow for generating the model in the GUI.

Comment: Check out this page https://class.stanford.edu/c4x/HumanitiesScience/StatLearning/asset/ch9.html

Comment: Yes sir, i have created the classification plot. I wanted to implement the model as a GUI in R. I wanted to predict the outcome based on the SVM model developed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do your GUI also in R by using R Shiny? Working simple GUI for SVM in R:

```
# Graphical user interface for support vector machines 
# If you don't have r shiny installed: install.packages("shiny")

library(shiny)
library(e1071)
library(MASS)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$svmSummary <- renderPrint({
    data(cats)
    svmmodel <- svm(Sex~., data = cats)
    print(summary(svmmodel))
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    "Simple UI for SVM"
    ),
    mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("svmSummary"))

  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

More information about R Shiny:[Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I had a small query. How would i be able to test the working of the gui for prediction of the class outcomes for new data. I had been looking out for this for my application.

Comment: just use your data instead of "cats"

Comment: Can the function be applied for both training and test data for prediction of the class variable sir. I wanted to create the ROC curve for the prediction as well.

Comment: Link to manual: [Manual](cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wanted to export the ROC Curve from the SVM classification to the GUI. Is it feasible using the Shiny package in R sir.

Comment: Edit you question and add R code to generate ROC curve. I am not familiar with SVM package.